# Python can print but cannot return statement

Tags: python

New user, please go easy on me.
Currently attempting leetcode twosum example and cannot return a statement. Oddly it prints when swapped out to the print keyword. The input example is [3,3] and should return [1,0] or [0,1] when the statement is returned. Looking at other questions on S/O it has to do with the subcall returning to the original loop but i still don't fully understand. Any tips?

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        self.nums = nums
        self.target = target
        nums = tuple(nums) #issue happens as a tuple and list.
        for x in nums:
            for y in nums:
                if (x+y) == target:
                    #print ([x,y])
                    if (nums.index(x)!=nums.index(y) ):
                        return([nums.index(x), nums.index(y)]) #this statement will normally print
                                                               # are any of the lines below necessary?
                    else:
                        continue
                    return
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What happens with [3, 3]?

Comment: Passing [3,3] as a List serves as an input. The output is an empty list.  "[]"

Comment: The answer to "are any of the lines below necessary?" is no.  :)  You'll never reach the `return`, and without that you'll just `continue` the loop regardless of the `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the values are the same, `nums.index(3)` will always equal `nums.index(3)` since it will always find the first `3`. To fix this, use `enumerate` to track the indices separately:

```py
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i, x in enumerate(nums):
            for j, y in enumerate(nums):
                if (x+y) == target:
                    if i != j:
                        return([i, j])
```

Comment: I appreciate the help everyone, thank you for the swift answers.